# How to pass GridList style props to GridListTile wrapped in other component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-beautiful-dnd

I'm having trouble with passing GridList style props that should be injected to GridListTile in map function. From what I have read and browsed so far, I found that it might be related to [Composition](https://material-ui.com/guides/composition/) in Material-Ui.

Here is my working code without wrapping it in a Draggable component from react-beautiful-dnd.

```
<GridList
    cellHeight={120}
    className={classes.gridList}
    cols={7}
    spacing={10}
    {...providedDroppable.droppableProps}
    ref={providedDroppable.innerRef}
>
    {data.items.map((item, index) => {
        return (
            <GridListTile key={item.key} cols={1}>
                <div className={classes.slot}></div>
                <GridListTileBar
                    title={item.name}
                    classes={{
                        root: classes.slotTitle,
                    }}
                />
            </GridListTile>
        );
    })}
    {providedDroppable.placeholder}
</GridList>
```

Here is the not working code with wrapping it in Draggable component

```
                            <GridList
                                cellHeight={120}
                                className={classes.gridList}
                                cols={7}
                                spacing={10}
                                {...providedDroppable.droppableProps}
                                ref={providedDroppable.innerRef}
                            >
                                {data.items.map((item, index) => {
                                    return (
                                        <Draggable
                                            key={item.key}
                                            draggableId={item.key}
                                            index={index}
                                        >
                                            {(providedDraggable) => {
                                                return (
                                                    <GridListTile
                                                        key={item.key}
                                                        cols={1}
                                                        ref={providedDraggable.innerRef}
                                                        {...providedDraggable.draggableProps}
                                                        {...providedDraggable.dragHandleProps}
                                                    >
                                                        <div className={classes.slot}></div>
                                                        <GridListTileBar
                                                            title={item.name}
                                                            classes={{
                                                                root: classes.slotTitle,
                                                            }}
                                                        />
                                                    </GridListTile>
                                                );
                                            }}
                                        </Draggable>
                                    );
                                })}
                                {providedDroppable.placeholder}
                            </GridList>
```